# What are these kind of problems called?

Tags: combinatorics, recursive-algorithms

**The question is that:**

> There are $100$ of coins, to be given to members of a family.
>
> The eldest brother is the one who decides how to distribute them
>   After his decision, family members vote if they accept it or not. The eldest brother also votes.
>
> If the accepted votes are equal or more than half, the decision is made.
>
> If not, the eldest brother will be killed, and the second-eldest brother will instead do the decision.
>
> The process continues until the decision is made.

**For example:**

If there are $2$ people, then $1$<sup>st</sup> person: $100$ and $2$<sup>nd</sup> person: $0$ (acceptance is $\dfrac{1}{2}$).

If there are $3$ people: then $1$<sup>st</sup> person: $99$, $2$<sup>nd</sup> person: $0$, and $3$<sup>rd</sup> person: $1$ (acceptance is $\dfrac{2}{3}$ by $1$<sup>st</sup> and $3$<sup>rd</sup>).

The reason is that if $3$<sup>rd</sup> person does not accept it, the $1$<sup>st</sup> person will be killed and thus $2$<sup>nd</sup> will make the decision, being same with the case of $2$ people. Thus, $3$<sup>rd</sup> person will get nothing.

I want to practice solving the problem like this one, but I have no idea what people called this kind of problems, and thus cannot find any problems to practice.

I think it's close to combinatorics (maybe) and recursive algorithm.

Please give any advice.

Comment: Please give your question a title that actually describes the content.

Comment: I call this kind of problem deeply tedious (particularly as your statement of the problem just describes a process without asking any questions about that process). What is it that you want to know about this process?

Comment: I was given the answer of the process.
and I want to practice this kind of thinking
but I don't know what is the quest called so I asked here

Comment: You say that if the votes in favor are more than one-half, the decision is accepted, but your examples seem to indicate that the decision is accepted if at least half the votes are in favor.  Otherwise, in the case of $n=2$ why doesn't the younger brother vote "No" and get all the coins?  Also, is each brother trying to maximize the number of coins he receives?

Comment: What do you want to know? A probability? A strategy? Or what?

Comment: I want to know how can I find more of these kind of question.
what is the topics it belongs to?

Comment: @saulspatz if the vote is equal or more than 50%, then the decision is made. In n=2, the 1st person votes yes and other no. so it's 50%.

Comment: You haven't given an example of a question! You have simply defined a hypothetical process. Where is the question mark in your "question"?

Comment: @RobArthan the question was to describe the process.

Comment: So if it's greater than or equal to one-half, that's what the question should say; not "more than one-half."  Please edit it.

Comment: @saulspatz I've edited that

Comment: This was on a TED talk about pirates - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mc6VA7Q1vXQ

Comment: @RexSolus: you have specified the rules of a process but you have not specified the goal.

Comment: https://ed.ted.com/lessons/can-you-solve-the-pirate-riddle-alex-gendler  This gives all the necessary hypotheses, as well as the objective.  Nice riddle.

Comment: @V.Chen I've just watched it. Still, it's didn't state what the topics this problem/process is in

Comment: Is your question just asking about where to find similar problems?

Comment: @user2825632 Yes, absolutely
I want to practice more of this kind

Comment: This is one dark question.

Comment: @an4s I agree ... pirates killing each other is one thing, but family members?!? Sheesh!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking about where to find similar problems. I've seen this problem before as a brain teaser/puzzle about pirates. To find similar puzzles, you can click any links in the "Games" topic at the bottom of the [Wikipedia page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_game). I would consider this a game theory problem.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of thinking behind this problem is called 'backwards induction'. Check out the 'Centipede game' for another example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve this problem completely? If there are $n$ family members, what is the acceptance? What if $n>100$ (very big family)? What if $n>200$?

The general formula is:
$$\frac{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil}{n}.$$
where $\lceil{x}\rceil$ is a ceiling function.